# How to separate compose spans like Gmail does?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ime

[image]

As you type on an EditText with autosuggestion enabled, the compose span, represented by the underlined text on the picture, is sectionized according to the stylespan I set on the toolbar. This is particularly helpful because otherwise the Google keyboard messes with the spans.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would reccomend you to decompile Gmail APK and see what they i've done. Maybe you could find something like a custom EditText which draw the text itself. You won't be able to use the code (will be obfuscated probably) but you could get a smart idea to start with

Comment: I thought about this but I think could be some other way. Evernote works the same way.